# how to wait for ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackgroud

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have a Utility function which I use to check if user has done few operations or not. If not, Then I need to send the results back to MainActivity.

```
public static boolean checkUserIsDone(String receiverPhoneNumber, String senderNumber ) {
    hasApp = false;
    HashMap<String, Object> parseParams = new HashMap<>();
    parseParams.put("phoneNumber", receiverPhoneNumber);
    parseParams.put("senderNumber", senderNumber);
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("GetUserByPhoneNumber", parseParams, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
        public void done(String result, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null && result.equals("success")) {
                hasApp = true;
            } else {
                hasApp = false;
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    return hasApp;
}
```